# Why I can not run npm run dev? ( node js /express js / type script)

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Guys can you please help me on this I have trouble run npm run dev for my project (node js /express js / type script)enter code here. I followed links below but still error exist.

PS C:\Users\Yasser\Documents\WorkspaceNodeJS\MeanCRA> npm run dev
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54617/2ce7f883-35f6-424d-80e5-91471fa1f1e8
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

> MEANCRA@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\Yasser\Documents\WorkspaceNodeJS\MeanCRA
> concurrently -n "TS, Node" "npx tsc --watch" "nodemon dist/index.js"

'concurrently' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MEANCRA@1.0.0 dev: `concurrently -n "TS, Node" "npx tsc --watch" "nodemon  dist/index.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MEANCRA@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yasser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-22T12_57_11_866Z-debug.log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiVBM.jpg)

My codes:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnWC5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN7H0.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH8AZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to upgrade NodeJS in your system. The error indicates that a minimum NodeJS version of 10 is required to use `yargs-parser` package.